# Scope parameter issue in SSRS report Expression

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Friends,
I have a detailed chart which represents individual expenses, but instead of handwritten fields, I want to use them from expression to load automatically as those fields are not the same every time. Hence I have used a Row Group with a Scope Parameter belonging to Row Grouping. More over I want them to have column wise Grouping based on Created Month.
But the issue is I am not able to add multiple Scope parameter to the expression.
Please find the images for better understanding here:
http://postimg.org/gallery/3eav75ja8/d73ae417/

image1 and image3 represent hand written fields.
image2 and image4 represent how I need, but the values for details are not correct.

Any guidance shall be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is the formula you are trying to use, that doesn't work?

Comment: Where do you need the row grouping ? In which cell ?

Comment: =Sum(IIf(Fields!category.Value = "DIRECT EXPENSES",Fields!Booking.Value,nothing), "statusfld")   "statusfld" is my row grouping, I also want column grouping with the column name = "Created_Month"

Comment: I need the grouping in image2 on 2nd column and 4th row

Comment: So in booking row cells you have the column grouping sum and now you want the row grouping sum in the `TotalDireactExpense` row right ?

Comment: Let it explain from beginning.. Don't consider the Booking field. Issue is regarding the amount against(that too month wise) the fields which fall under Direct Expenses (Lorry Hire Charges, Local Collection Charges, etc.). But these fields are not fixed to hardcode them. So i used row grouping(with "statusfld" as scope parameter). Now the fields are showing up properly but their amount field is the sum of all months(It can be solved by using scope parameter which you had suggested in previous question). If i add "created_month" as scope parameter i must hardcode all fields which i don't want..

Comment: In simple words, here is my expression:     =Sum(IIf(Fields!category.Value = "DIRECT EXPENSES",Fields!Booking.Value,nothing), "statusfld")     I want to add one more scope parameter "created_month" along with "statusfld"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it was bit complicated, But my new friend "INSCOPE" did the trick for me!!

=IIf(Inscope("Created_Month") and Inscope("statusfld"),Sum(IIf(Fields!category.Value = "DIRECT EXPENSES",Fields!Booking.Value,nothing)),Sum(IIf(Fields!category.Value = "DIRECT EXPENSES",Fields!Booking.Value,nothing)))

Thank you!